# How to run the powershell script from ansible tower on windows machine by encrypting the domain account

Tags: powershell, ansible

I want to run powershell script to stop some application which will use the domain account , I want to encrypt the domain user and password .

The application uses URL to login with domain username and password

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to store account credentials (especially password) for an automated email script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50917375/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-account-credentials-especially-password-for-an-a)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this [credential tutorial](https://www.pdq.com/blog/secure-password-with-powershell-encrypting-credentials-part-1/). Example store password in encrypted format in file:

```
"P@ssword1" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File "C:\Temp 2\Password.txt"
```

Comment: How to run the powershell script from ansible linux server

Comment: Install Powershell [core] (https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases). Depending on your distro it may also be available via a package manager. Powrshell core supports remoting via SSH.